# WPF prevent lost focus on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to fully prevent lostFocus from a TextBox?

I would like to prevent any action from app(button clicks, switching focus to other TextBoxes) until I meet some conditions

I have figured out how to prevent switching focus from a TextBox, but this does not help with button clicks/commands:

```
textBox.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += (sender, args) =>
{
    if(textBox.Text != "test")
    args.Handled = true;
};
```

But right now: how to disallow clicking on Buttons? (perfectly - disallow everything until I meet specific conditions)

Answer (score 1):

Disable all your button by default.
Then in your event, enable button by your conditions.

Comment: My view is too complex to do it. I have multiple levels of controls, so I cannot just handle it on every button etc.

Comment: Please try to give me more information. Meanwhile here some suggestions: 1) Bind the disable option to your View model list with Boolean property. 2) Loop on element and enable all his button's children.

Comment: yes bind all your other controls Enabled="{Binding MyEnabledBool}".